# Nodejs + ExpressJS + Jade + Post no render

Tags: jquery, node.js, pug, express

1˚ - Client:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    url: '/someposturl',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        // $('body').html(data); // i don't want it, but if not so, nothing happens (render) 
    }
});
```

2˚ - Server:

```
app.get('/criptografar', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.something);
    res.render('somepage', {
        somevar: withsomevalue
    });
    //-I want this to work like a normal post
});
```

3˚ - Client -> 'somepage' - not rendered without this in the client:

```
$('body').html(data); // i don't want it, but if not so, nothing happens (render)
```

or this

```
$('html').html(data); // i don't want it, but if not so, nothing happens (render) <- Jade Layout error.
```

Comment: And what is supposed to happen? You are doing ajax call and server responds with data as you can clearly see. Do you understand what ajax is? :) If you want it to work like a normal POST you can for example return URL from server and do `location.href = url;`.

Comment: Please format your code properly next time; while others are likely to do it quickly it's not nice to let them do something you can easily do, too.

Comment: You should use **app.post(**  instead of app.get(

Answer (score -1):

Because you call it from `$.ajax` from client side.
It works good if you call it from server side

To make a page call a URL from server side, you should add this to your form

```
form(role="form" method="POST")
```

Please refer to this question.
[Express.js Won't Render in Post Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301254/express-js-wont-render-in-post-action?noredirect=1#comment41284301_26301254)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Okay, noted @Rory-McCrossan