# Express.js Won't Render in Post Action

Tags: node.js, post, express, pug, render

Node.js is kinda new, so I hardly can find things in internet.
I have already solved this. It was because I was calling from client side using `$.ajax`.
But when I try it in my code below, it never renders.
The initial page was /contact, and when I call /contact/sendEmail, all of the function inside /contact/sendEmail are working but not with the render.
There was no error at all. It was just like nothing happened.

```
var Contact = require('../controllers/contact');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/contact', function(req, res) {
    res.render('contact');
  });
  app.post('/contact/sendEmail', function(req, res, next) {
    var form = req.body;
    Contact.validators.form(form, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.render('user/register'); //This one never works!
        /*return res.render('contact', {
          error: err,
        });*/
      } else {
        Contact.sendEmail(req, res, next);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

It was called by this function

```
$('.contact').submit(function(event, done) {
  var form = $(this);
  var data = form.serializeArray();
  // server side validation
  // every contact form field is required
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/contact/sendEmail',
    data: form.serialize()
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'OK') {
      $('#contact-success').modal('show');
    } else {
      return done('Please fill all of the fields.', false);
    }
  });
});
```

For everybody to learn.
I changed it to call from server side by adding this to the jade file:

```
form(role="form" method="POST")
```

Comment: Define "never renders." Do you get an error? What (template) do you see on the front-end?

Comment: Thx @mscdex, I didn't expect the reply will be this fast.
I have updated the question. It doesn't show any error. It just plainly don't want to render. The problem is only on the render. Beside of it, all are working.

Comment: If `user/register` is not being rendered to the front end, what do you see on the client side though after POSTing to `/contact/sendEmail`? A blank page? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully solved it by myself!
I found out that it happened because I call the route from `$.ajax` from the client.
When I change the calling method by putting this code into the form and remove the `$.ajax`, it's done. Thank you @mscdex

```
form(role="form" method="POST")
```

and I changed the route `/contact/sendEmail` to just `/contact`.