# Page not rendered from Express POST route

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm trying to display a page using a POST route, but so far no luck. The route is called from an Angular controller. The POST route is called properly - I get this in the node console `POST /search 200 673ms` - but the page is not displayed. If I Invoke the route directly from the browser (i.e. typing the address) it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

I've found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327397/page-not-getting-rendered-via-express-when-using-post-nodejs), but the solution posted there doesn't work for me.

Here's my code:
Angular Controller

```
function SearchController($scope, $http){
   $scope.product = {...};

   $scope.search = function(form) {
      $http.post('/search', { product : $scope.product });
   };
}
```

Route definition

```
  var products = require('../app/controllers/products')
  app.post('/search', auth.requiresLogin, products.results)
```

Route controller

```
exports.results = function (req, res) {
   // build query and fields var

   Product.find(query, fields, function (err, docs) {
      res.render('products/results', {
        title: 'Search Results',
        user: req.user ? JSON.stringify(req.user) : "null",
        searchResults: docs ? docs : "null"
      })
   });
}
```

I'm using Express 3.3.3, Node 0.10.9 and Angular 1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **trying to render** an express page through your $http call , it will just not work. You should only request data through ajax,not pages.

If you need to redirect to page , use the $window service , in the ajax callback.

```
$window.location="/search";
```

if your express controller renders json there should be no problem. but since you are using the method `res.render` i understand it is not the case.

Comment: Thanks @mpm, that pointed me in the right direction. I'm now using `res.json` in my `find` method to return json back to the Angular Controller and then to the Jade template